# Using Management Studio on Linux

Tags: ssms, linux

Is it possible to use Management Studio in Linux? I want to connect to my SQL Server instances with an IDE. How can i do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you very much. As far as i can see, there is no alternative tool for the situation. Is it right?

Comment: You can check out the many DBMS independent SQL tools

Comment: Virtual Machines are easily created these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS runs on Windows only. If you're looking for a Microsoft tool, check out [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-ver15). There are also [third-party tools](https://alternativeto.net/software/sql-server-management-studio/?platform=linux) available for Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.